# Diophantine Equation - least values for n : absolute values

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm

Find all solutions to the diophantine equation

$323x + 278y = 7$

Choose also a solution for which $|x| + |y|$ is as small as possible.

My approach to this is to do the usual euclidean algorithm

$278 = 0*323 + 278  \quad ...  \quad  2 = 2*1 + 0$

Then i do the extended euclidean algorithm to drive it back up

$1 = (1 * 3) + (-1 * 2)  \quad ...  \quad 1 = (122 * 278) + (-105 * 323)$

The particular solution is $x_0 = -735, \quad y_0 = 854$

and the particular solution is $x = -735 + 278n, \quad y = 854 - 323n$

Upto this point, we're all good. But the problem is choosing the least value of n that produces $|x| + |y|$.

My approach to this has always been to try out different values of n until i find the answer. It takes quite a lot of time but i think out there, theres gotta be some sort of a quick method to the most suitable value of n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you started correctly.

$$
x = −735+278n\\
y=854−323n\\
$$

You can quickly minimize $\mid x \mid$ by choosing $n \approx \frac{735}{278}$ so either $n=2,3$ will be best. For $2$ you get $-179$ and for $3$ you get $99$.

Now do $\mid y \mid$. $n \approx \frac{854}{323}$ so either $n=2,3$ will be best.
For $2$ you get $208$ and for $3$ you get $-115$.

$n=3$ minimizes both individually so it will minimize the sum $\mid x \mid + \mid y \mid$. There is no conflict between minimizing the summands individually. This is a lucky case.

Comment: OK, i think its indeed a lucky case. But what if i get in a situation where its not a lucky case, is there any other quick way to determine the values of n? For example if i have an equation lets say $756x + 278y = 12600$, it generates very huge values of x and y namely $x = 359100 + 139n \quad and \quad y = -976500 - 378n$ The values become too huge to try out with the above methodology. Is there any other quicker method to determine the value of n?

Answer (score 0):

For example for $x(n)=359100+139n \space $ and $y(n)=-976500-378n$ we have 2 cases, to the function $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$:
$$g(n)=f(x,y)=-x+y=-1335600-517n, \space n \leq -2584 $$
$$g(n)=f(x,y)=x-y=1335600+517n, \space n \geq -2583 $$

So we want to minimize g (same function as f), choosing the best value of n. There could have been 3 cases, but because both x and y change sign for the same n there is no intermediate case. See how the value of g(n) changes when n changes to either side from the intersection, it always grows. So we conclude that the best value of n must be $-2584$ or $-2583$. Evaluating:
$$g(-2583)=189$$
$$g(-2584)=328$$

Therefore, the best n is $n=-2583$

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit more? I suppose you mean that in respect to the question i posted in the comments section, if $x=359100+139n$, then i take the derivative with respect to n which will be $139$ what does 139 mean in this case? and how do i approach it depending on the sign of either x or y

Comment: The derivate is just to know how your function behaves. I updated the answer explaining this.